# Laravel Spatie Honeypot package not installing on Laravel 5.5.49

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am on Laravel 5.5.49 and am trying to install this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-honeypot

But when I get the error message it gives me the following message:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Installation request for spatie/laravel-honeypot ^2.2 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-honeypot[2.2.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - spatie/laravel-honeypot 2.2.0 requires illuminate/validation ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/validation[v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.14.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/validation v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^5.5.49 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.49, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.40, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.29, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
```

A little confused by which versions this honeypot package supports for Laravel. From the error message it looks nothing is support up 5.8.38

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolve this issue? Which version were you installing?

Answer (score -1):

You are right, `spatie/laravel-honeypot` support Laravel v5.7+

```
0.0.1
2018-12-27 09:06 UTC
requires

php: ^7.1
illuminate/contracts: ^5.7
illuminate/encryption: ^5.7
illuminate/http: ^5.7
illuminate/support: ^5.7
illuminate/validation: ^5.7
```